# laravel unable to handle exception, catch block not executing

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5.6

I am on my way to creating an SSH Bot that performs various operations on the remote servers. The username and passwords for these servers are provided by the user.

But when the user provides wrong username or password or a wrong IP address of the server then it throws `ErrorException` exception.

I want to handle that exception and store error message in the database. Instead of showing it to the user.

here is my code

```
try {
                $pending_server->console_output = $this->setupDNS($pending_server->toArray());
                $pending_server->status = 'Configured';
            } catch (ErrorException $e) {
                $pending_server->console_output = $e->getMessage;
                $pending_server->status = 'Failed';
                $pending_server->save();
            }
```

In the database `$pending_server` is the database model. The `setupDNS` method is throwing the exception.
Therefore in case of an exception, I want to store the error message as the output in the database. But the catch block is not executing at all and execution of script stops.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see what the logs say. You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 3);` before you initiate the SSH connection.

Comment: @neubert I know the reason for the exception so what would I do after seeing the log

Comment: I just want to know why the catch block is not being executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put '\' before ErrorException. For eg:

```
try {
                $pending_server->console_output = $this->setupDNS($pending_server->toArray());
                $pending_server->status = 'Configured';
            } catch (\ErrorException $e) {
                $pending_server->console_output = $e->getMessage;
                $pending_server->status = 'Failed';
                $pending_server->save();
            }
```